# Can I specify different decimal places using the function np.savetxt()

Tags: python, file-io, numpy

Can I use the np.savetxt() to specify diferente decimal places in each column?
Data is an array with 2923 lines and with 10 columns.

```
def Write_file(path,header,data):
         fid = open(path,'w') # open file (w)
         for i in xrange(len(header)):
                  fid.write(header[i]) # write header
         np.savetxt(fid,data,fmt='%7.3f')
         fid.close() # close file
         return True
```

I tried this insted of using np.savetxt() but does not work. This is the output format that I need

```
for i in xrange(2923):
             fid.write('%i   %7.0f  %7.4f  %7.4f  %7.3f  %7.3f  %7.3f  %7.3f  %7.3f  %7.3f'%(data[i,0],data[i,1],data[i,2],data[i,3],data[i,4],data[i,5],data[i,6],data[i,7],data[i,8],data[i,9]))
```

Comment: have you tried passing directly `fmt='%i   %7.0f  %7.4f  %7.4f  %7.3f  %7.3f  %7.3f  %7.3f  %7.3f  %7.3f'` to `savetxt`?

Comment: @flebool you can post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass directly

`fmt='%i %7.0f %7.4f %7.4f %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f'`

to `savetxt`. As the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) says, you can pass a multi-format string, e.g. `'Iteration %d – %10.5f'`